# add image to pdf using jsPDF and Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jspdf, html2canvas

I would get an image from a Html element then add it to a a pdf.

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', 'a4');
pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 0.75;
const logo = html2canvas(document.getElementById('activityLogo'))
pdf.addImage(logo, 'jpeg');
pdf.save(`file.pdf`);
```

in my html:

```
<ng-template #exportImage>
    <div class="pt-2 pb-5">
        <img alt="Information" id="activityLogo" src="assets/img/brand/png/Logo.png" width="100" />
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

actually I get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null
```

**EDIT**:
I added a new line

```
const elm= document.getElementById('activityLogo')
console.log(elm)
```

the result is `null`.

May be the error is from here but I don't know why I get `null`

Comment: What's the line where ownerDocument appears?

Comment: it apprears at `const logo = html2canvas(document.getElementById('activityLogo'))
`

Comment: It seems that you have a line where you define a var named ownerDocument. Where is it?

Comment: It could be a known issue with html2canvas.  https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1367

Comment: see comment _Move the div element (whatever you're targeting) above the script tag call (where you call the html2canvas() function, not where you load the script itself)_

Comment: That does not worked, I have updated my answer